# Why can't functions call each other inside my <App /> component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have the following two functions inside my `<App />` component and they are placed just before the render() method. I would like `open_theme_FUNCTION` to be able to call `new_or_open_so_clear_workspace_FUNCTION` but it is out of scope and not declared. Why is this?

```
    new_or_open_so_clear_workspace_FUNCTION = (that) => {
      that.setState({
        start_show_or_hide : false,
        application_menu_show_or_hide : false,
        workspace_background : "white"
      });
    }

    open_theme_FUNCTION = () => {
      console.log("Opening a project")
      new_or_open_so_clear_workspace_FUNCTION(this)
      // code
    };
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect it to be a class component, so you only have to use `this`.

```
open_theme_FUNCTION = () => {
   console.log("Opening a project")
   this.new_or_open_so_clear_workspace_FUNCTION(this)
   // code
};
```

And you also should avoid passing around `this`. Your example should work without doing that.